# Is there any free way to search github that isn't severely limited and simple (aka: searching for special characters or using regex)?

Tags: regex, github

So it seems like google console is paid for github (I can't find a free way to search the contents in repos, only their names and metadata) and also the github search doesn't even allow me to search for "=" let alone more complex regex like ^.*[$]var[=]foo or so. Are we limited to simple search only? thanx

Comment: do you mean - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains

Comment: Could you explain further how is your question related to BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to have a look at Hound:

- Github: https://github.com/hound-search/hound
- Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/etsy/hound

  > Hound is an extremely fast source code search engine. The core is based on this article (and code) from Russ Cox: Regular Expression Matching with a Trigram Index. Hound itself is a static React frontend that talks to a Go backend. The backend keeps an up-to-date index for each repository and answers searches through a minimal API.

We use it for searching through several projects in our codebase.